# Individual user favourite question categorisation

Tags: feature-request

When reading questions we often find snippets of code and explanations etc that really help us in our own work later on. However the question title *and purpose or focus* (rendering the editing of questions or titles not possible) may not relate directly to the part of the question or answer that helps each user.

*"Favouriting"* these questions allows us to save them to look up later as we wish, however it is often challenging to remember which questions were favourited for what reason, especially when question titles or purpose do not relate directly to the benefit gained.

Would it be possible to add a system where users can organise in folders or with associated short notes or descriptions such that users could then easily access the specific questions they want for the information they need?

Comment: One does want this.

Comment: i have proposed something like that but unfortunately i was told to use bookmarks bar ...